# Are all elements of a quaternion algebra regular elliptic semisimple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

I have some issues with these definitions and maybe the not enough explicit definition of quaternion algebras. Let $D$ be a division quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$. The question is the one of the title:

- (1) Are all the elements of $D$ or $D/Z$ regular?
- (2) Are all the elements of $D$ or $D/Z$ elliptic?
- (3) Are all the elements of $D$ or $D/Z$ semisimple?

Thanks for any clue!

Comment: What did you try? Perhaps you should only post one or two questions at a time.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have the impression that all these questions are related. At least, involve some "centralizer" computations that I don't understand well. For instance $x$ is elliptic if it is semisimple and the maximal split subtorus of the centralizer of $x$ is equal to the maximal split subtorus of the center of $D$. And it is regular if the dimension of this centralizer is the size of a maximal split torus of $D$. Am I at least right with the definitions? Maybe indeed they should be asked separately, but since they are somewhat related, I anticipated a similar treatment...

Answer (score 4):

Let $D$ be a quaternion division algebra over a field $F$.  Then, for $\alpha \in D - F$, the centralizer of $\alpha$ in $D$ is the quadratic extension $E=F[\alpha]$.  Note $E$ is not split since $D$ is division, so $\alpha$ is regular, elliptic and semisimple.  (Elements in $F$ are not regular.)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly the kind of key point I was hoping for. So there is a characterization of "regular, elliptic, semisimple" in terms of $F(\alpha)$? Where can I find such information and proofs?

Comment: @Wolker I would guess most treatments of quaternion algebras/CSA.  For instance, see the proof of Theorem 3.1.3 in [my notes](http://www.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/quaint/).